Затык с динамичными выпадающими списками в google sheets
возникла проблема с выпадающими списками.
То что в эксель решается одной простой формулой в поле источника, гугль, зараза, по умолчанию не умеет.
Нужен динамичный выпадающий список, который выбирает лист-источник исходя из значения ячейки в строке. Диапазоны на листах одинаковы.
Все найденные инструкции по динамичным спискам делают немного другое, хотя, подозреваю, нужное мне даже проще.
То что надо сделанное в эксель:


Добрый день! Списки в гугл также имеют возможность добавления формулы. Приведите пример в таблице по типу "пробовал"-"хочу" и вышлите ссылку.
